# c++ using std::copy to copy an istream to a char* buffer

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

Is there a way to copy a std::istream to a buffer of data accessed by a "data()" method which returns a char*? For instance, the below code example. It results in a segfault. I know I could use std::back_inserter in this example, but my goal is not to copy to a vector ultimately.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
int main() {
  std::vector<char> vec;
  std::istringstream ss("foobar");
  std::copy(std::istream_iterator<char>(ss), std::istream_iterator<char> 
  (),vec.data());
}
```

Comment: What about `ss.read(buff, buff + sizeof(buff))`?

Comment: Your vector contains zero elements, so you cannot write to elements that are not allocated yet. You'd have to resize the vector first (or otherwise provide an allocated buffer to copy to)

Comment: You can't copy *anything* to an empty vector, be it via file stream iterators or anything else. The `data()` member, and in fact the *vector*, is irrelevant, honestly. You're copying data from an iterator range to a *target*. Ultimately it is your responsibility to ensure that target is either sufficient in capacity to accept that copy, or the target is sufficiently intelligent enough to make space along the way. The code presented does *neither*.

Comment: "_but my goal is not to copy to a vector ultimately_": What does that mean? Why does using `std::back_inserter` prevent you from reaching this ultimate goal?

Comment: What is your actual goal? we should be able to help you with that

Comment: Do you know anything about the size of the input stream ahead of time? If yes, pre-allocate storage on the vector using `.reserve()` and use `std::back_inserter`, and you should have no reallocations. If no, still use `std::back_inserter`, because you can't avoid possible reallocations if you don't know the size ahead of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No problem to copy provided enough storage is allocated upfront:

```cpp
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
int main()
{
  std::vector<char> vec(6); //note what happens here!
  std::istringstream ss("foobar");
  std::copy(std::istream_iterator<char>(ss), std::istream_iterator<char> 
  (), vec.data());
}
```